# Find the locus in the “circle point midpoint theorem”.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

This is a simplified version of the “circle point midpoint theorem”.

Q is a point external to the circle $C : x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. P is a point on C. M is the midpoint of PQ. Find the locus of M as P moves along C.

[image]

I managed to find the answer by:-

(1) Get A and B, the points of intersections of QO extended with C.

(2) Find $M_1$ and $M_2$, the midpoints of QA and QB respectively.

(3) **Knowing** that the locus of M is a circle with $M_1$ and $M_2$ as its extremities, I form its equation. It happens to be the equation of the locus of M.

My work depends heavily on the assumption that the locus is a circle which is not supposed to be known beforehand. So, I am wondering is there another way to find the required locus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q$ is a point with coordinates $(a,0)$ with $a\le -r$. A generic point in your circle has coordinates $(r\cos t, r\sin t)$. The midpoint has coordinates
$$
(\frac{a+r\cos t}{2},\frac{r\sin t}{2})
$$
Excluding $t$ we clearly have $(2x-a)^2+(2y)^2=r^2$ or
$$
(x-a/2)^2+y^2=(r/2)^2
$$
which is a circle of radius $r/2$ centered at $(a/2,0)$.

Comment: Didn't realize I can use parametric form. That is what I want.